# Dell laptop battery is dead. Computer appears to not be charging

Tags: battery

Last night my computer was working fine.  Low battery, so I plugged in it.  A little bit of charge before I unplugged it and left it for the night.  I thought there should have been a bit of battery left this morning, but I guess not.  Now the battery is completely dead.  When I plug in it, there is no light indicating it is charging.  Could my charger have mysteriously broken during the night, or is it a problem with the computer?  Suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Check the charger with a multimeter to ensure it's outputting the right voltage. If the battery is a couple years old, it's probably time to replace it.

Comment: trouble with that method is there's no way to check that the PSU can supply that voltage under load, only with no load. PSUs get 'tired' over time & can easily supply the full voltage when there's no work to do, yet fail abysmally when there is.

Comment: Jennifer, you mentioned "When I plug in it, there is no light indicating it is charging". What about the system tray icon (The bar across the bottom of the screen, if you are using Windows)?  There should be an small white icon that shows the state of the laptop battery.  Does *that* show it charging or does it have a blank battery with an X through it?  If it is the latter, your battery probably died.

I would also recommend turning off the laptop and trying to reseat the battery.  Just pop it out and try and put it back in.  Also check the connection pins to see if they are dirty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have or could borrow a different power cord first I would start there. If it doesn't work with a different power cord though, I've seen a couple Dell laptops quit charging because of the power jack socket on the computer.  Dell had a bad power jack socket design (IMO) that breaks easy internally, due to the leverage the power cord creates on it. It takes some skill to open a laptop and replace this though. But if you feel confident with small parts, clips, and screws, they are fairly cheap on eBay or Amazon. ex: [http://www.amazon.com/Power-Socket-Harness-Dell-Inspiron/dp/B009G8185I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420222397&sr=8-1&keywords=dell+power+jack+socketcould](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009G8185I) (except obviously you would look up your exact model this is just an exapmle)